# WinUI3 H.NotifyIcon, Unable to resolve symbol TaskbarIcon

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, notifyicon

I am working on a winui3 project, and for notify icon, only good option I found is **HavenDV/H.NotifyIcon**

For winui, it recommends **H.NotifyIcon.WinUI**, but it is having version issues and showing
[image]

So, I tried to add the core library **H.NotifyIcon**, which supposedly works for all the platforms, but it is showing `Unable to resolve symbol 'TaskbarIcon'`

[image]

So, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, I guess you are getting this error because, the latest H.NotifyIcon.WinUI requires WindowsAppSDK **v1.2.230217.4** or later, but your app has   WindowsAppSDK **v1.2.221109.1** installed.

Updating WindowsAppSDK to the latest version should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I test it and I couldn't reproduce the issue.

1,In `manage nuget packages`, find the `H.NotifyIcon.winui package` and install it.

[image]

2,Declared within MainWindow

```
<Window
        xmlns:tb="clr-namespace:H.NotifyIcon;assembly=H.NotifyIcon.Wpf" // WPF
    xmlns:tb="using:H.NotifyIcon" // WinUI
    >
        <tb:TaskbarIcon
            ToolTipText="ToolTip"
        IconSource="/Images/TrayIcons/Logo.ico"
            ContextFlyout="{StaticResource TrayMenu}"
            MenuActivation="LeftOrRightClick"
            TrayPopup="{StaticResource TrayStatusPopup}"
            PopupActivation="DoubleClick"
            TrayToolTip="{StaticResource TrayToolTip}"
            />
</Window>
```

**Note:** 1,WinUI uses `ContextFlyout` instead `ContextMenu`.

```
2,Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK>=1.2.230217.4
```

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:

https://github.com/HavenDV/H.NotifyIcon